# Get touch Location and tap on monogame

Tags: android, monogame

I'm writing a game in monogame for Android for my school project but I can't get touch location to do one simple tap action, I search but I can't find anything useful to do that. My game is a pipe puzzle game that I want when player touch a pipe it rotate but as I say I can't do this. this is my code for keyboard input.

```
        KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space) && newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
                angle1 += (float)Math.PI / 2.0f;
        }
        oldState = newState;
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to add a check for the following:

```
TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();

    if (touchCollection.Count > 0)
    {
         //Only Fire Select Once it's been released
         if (touchCollection[0].State == TouchLocationState.Moved || touchCollection[0].State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
         {
              Console.WriteLine(touchCollection[0].Position);
         {
    }
```

You can then do what ever you want with the Position variable.